# Need help with the proof of "If a graph $G$ contains a $u − v$ walk of length $l$, then $G$ contains a $u − l$ path of length at most $l$".

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$Proof$. Among all $u − v$ walks in $G$, let $P = (u = u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_k = v)$ be a $u − v$ walk of smallest length $k$. Therefore, $k \le l$. We claim that $P$ is a $u − v$ path. Assume, to the contrary, that this is not the case. Then some vertex of $G$ must be repeated in $P$, say $u_i = u_j$ for some $i$ and $j$ with $0 \le i < j \le k$. If we then delete the vertices $u_{i + 1}, u_{i + 2}, \ldots,$ $u_j$ from $P$, we arrive at the $u − v$ walk $(u = u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_{i - 1}, u_i = u_j, u_{j + 1}..., u_k = v)$ whose length is less than $k$, which is impossible. Therefore, as claimed, $P$ is a $u − v$ path of length $k \le l$.

How can $u_i = u_j$ if $i < j$? Why do we specifically remove $u_{i + 1}, u_{i + 2}, \dots, u_j$? If $u_i = u_j$, then $u_{i + 1} = u_{j + 1}$, so then why is $u_{j + 1}$  not removed from the walk of length $k$ along with $u_j$?

Comment: what is a u-l path?

Comment: I am not sure, it's worded that way in my textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't conclude that $u_{i+1}$ is the same as $u_{j+1}$ simply because $u_i=u_j$. The point of deleting the stuff in between is that if you imagine travelling through the path, if there is a repeated vertex $r$ then that means all of the travelling you did to get from vertex $r$ back to vertex $r$ was a detour, you could have selected not to take the detour and would have still reached your final destination, this would have been a shorter walk, and this contradicts the fact that you had supposedly selected the shortest walk.

Comment: In the proof it says that $u_j$ is removed from $P$, but $u_j$ is still in $(u = u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_{i - 1}, u_i = u_j, u_{j + 1}..., u_k = v)$. Can you elaborate on that, please.

Comment: he just removed all the part that goes from u_i back to u_j, which is also u_i

Answer (score 0):

> How can $u_i=u_j$ if $i<j$?

This is just saying that one of the vertices in the walk $P$ is repeated. We have to remember that $P$ is a **sequence** of vertices, and $j$ comes later in the sequence than $i$. We can see this from:

> $u_i=u_j$ for some $i$ and $j$ with $0\leq i<j\leq k$

We remove $u_{i+1},u_{i+2},\cdots,u_j$ because we want to get rid of the portion of the sequence that just took us from $u_i$ back to $u_i$. Remember, we want a path, and by definition, a path is a sequence of vertices where no vertex is repeated.